# Is there any advanced console test runner for xUnit.net

Tags: mono, xunit.net

I am searching for an advanced console based test runner for xUnit.net. The requirements are:

- It should be able list all executed tests
- It should be able to list all tests within an assembly
- You should be able to filter the tests by namespace, class name and method name
- It should work with mono
- automatic reexecution of the tests after compilation would be nice

Do you know any?

Comment: [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286725.aspx)

Comment: Haven't used xUnit.net myself yet, but from a quick look at its homepage, it seems to include a console runner that can be integrated with MSBuild.  You may be able to use that with Mono's xbuild, but no promises, just an idea.

Comment: Might be useful to log some of these ideas/requirements as issues on the relevant runners themselves. are you definitely ruling out the .gui runner ? I guess you excluded it and I know the sort of thing you're after, but would you consider it? BTW IIRC the guys are making reference to doing a WPF GUI at some stage (which obviously makes it worse for mono)...). Also you might find the xunit discussions page a better place to ask as you're asking 5 things...

Comment: Unfortunately the included gui runner doesn't work for me on linux. The icons are not shown. Thus I cannot see which tests failed and which were successfull. Even if it worked, I would still prefer a console based runner because I have the feeling that it makes me much more productive. I try to do all repetitive work on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The new AssemblyRunner should be able to do some of the things on your requirements list now such as listing tests

For an example of it's use see the sample on github.
https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/TestRunner/Program.cs

the existing xunit.runner.console can filter tests using traits also